# My keyboard cannot input "1", maybe caused by shortcut setting

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

My keyboard cannot input "1", I believe it physically works because when I login in Ubuntu with 1, it works.

This problem occurs after I setting some new input method and setting one shortcut。

Now how could I reset all the shortcuts and make the “1” works again。

I had checked keyboard--keyboard setting ， and reset it all but still not work

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings > Devices > Keyboard > Reset all

and

Reboot.

[image: Reset]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Actually, I had reset all but still doesn' t work.                 
 I remember I Set somewhere "Ctrl +1", not in the system, more like in an Input Method . while now I uninstall all input method, still not work.

Comment: After removing package dont forget to [remove configuration files](https://ccm.net/faq/8269-ubuntu-cleaning-up-configuration-residue-packages).and [See this also.](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/im-config.8.html)